# Unwanted characters in DataTable filter options - JS JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, datatable

Could someone assist me in resolving this issue with the DataTable? I'm trying to filter rows by a column value and struggling to find a way to remove [the "> characters that appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gj35g.png).

```
var a = $("#datatable-buttons").DataTable({
    lengthChange: !1,
    buttons: [{
        className: 'btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm waves-effect rounded-pill waves-light',
        text: '<i class="mdi mdi-account-plus-outline"></i> Add User',
        init: function(api, node, config) {
            $(node).removeClass('btn-secondary');
        },
        action: function(e, dt, node, config) {
            //This will send the page to the location specified
            window.location.href = 'add_user.php';
        }
    }],
    ordering: false,
    pageLength: 20,
    lengthChange: false,
    scrollY: "550px",
    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns().every(function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select class="form-select form-select-sm"><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo($(column.header()).empty())
                .on('change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                        .draw();
                });

            column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
            });
        });
    }
});

a.buttons().container().appendTo("#datatable-buttons_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)");
$(".dataTables_length label").addClass("form-label");
```

Comment: I suspect there are quotes in `d` that cause `'<option value="' + d + '">'` to be parsed incorrectly.

Comment: Can you show the output of `console.log(column.data().unique())`?

Comment: `.every()` should be `.each()`. `.every()` is a boolean function that returns true if a condition is true for every element of the array.

Comment: On my end, this won't function as intended. I encounter an error when the table row contains a <span>, but it functions correctly when the table row is standard without any <span> elements.
Just view this image: https://ibb.co/4svSvvG
@Barmar

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
                select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
```

to

```
                select.append($('<option>', {
                    value: d,
                    text: d
                });
```

There are characters in `d` that are causing the HTML to be misparsed. Using the object-oriented method avoids this.

Comment: On my end, this won't function as intended. I encounter an error when the table row contains a <span>, but it functions correctly when the table row is standard without any <span> elements.
Just view this image: https://ibb.co/4svSvvG

Comment: You can't put `<span>` inside `<option>`, so I'm not sure what your desired result is supposed to be in that case.